# How do I solve $\sin x+x\cos x=0\,$?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

> How do I solve $\sin x+x\cos x=0\,$?

I've tried several different trigonometric identities and I'm aware it can be also written as $$\tan x=-x.$$ One of the answers is zero, but the other answers elude me. I've tried graphing $\tan x$ and $y=-x$ simultaneously as well, but I want to find the answer numerically.

Comment: I don't think the answers to this equation are nice...

Comment: The graph $y = \tan x$ and $y=-x$ intersect infinitely many time, one in every $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)+n\pi$.

Comment: Try defining $f(x)=\tan(x)+x$ and proving that it is strictly increasing using the derivative.

Comment: $x \approx -11.085538406497022543376125$.

Comment: *I want to find the answer numerically* --- See [Numerical solution to x = tan (x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305538/13130) AND [Derivation of asymptotic solution of $\tan(x) = x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110256/13130) AND [Solution of tanx = x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18718/13130)

Comment: @PQH What would that show us, precisely? The strict monotonicity and continuity of $f$ wouldn't imply injectivity since $f$ isn't defined in every $\pi/2 + n\pi$ ...

Comment: @Vardenmeersch it shows that the solution $x=0$ is unique at an interval. Then you can try the same at the other intervals.

Comment: This is the transcendental equation, which does not have an analytical solution. You can solve it numerically using the Newton method. Define $f(x)=\text{tan}(x)+x$, set $x_0$ and solve $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$. Solve it for different $x_0$ (see graph of $f(x)$ to know where to start).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the discontinuities introduced by the tangent, keep the equation as $$\sin( x)+x\cos (x)=0$$
The roots will be closer and closer to $x_0^{(n)}=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$. So, make  series expansion around this point and then series reversion.

Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361079/sin-x-x-cos-x-0-solution/1365514#1365514a) for simple approximations.